# saving userform inputs in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, userform

I'm trying to use userforms in word VBA to save an undefined number of variables into an array to later input in a document but I can't get the incremental counter to work and it will only save the last input and it is saved as input 0.

```
Public i As Integer
Sub Macro6()
    UF1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddC_Click()
Dim CName(100) As String
Dim CAddress(100) As String

CName(i) = txtName.Text
CAddress(i) = txtAddress.Text

i = i + 1

Unload Me
UF1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
Dim CName(100) As String
Dim CAddress(100) As String
Dim n As Integer

CName(i) = txtName.Text
CAddress(i) = txtAddress.Text

Unload Me

For n = 0 To i
  Selection.TypeText Text:="Client number " & n & " is " & CName(n) & "."
  Selection.TypeParagraph
  Selection.TypeText Text:="Client number " & n & " is " & CAddress(n) & "."
  Selection.TypeParagraph
Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
txtName.Text = ""
txtAddress.Text = ""
End Sub
```

The output is always:

Client number 0 is a.
Client number 0 is b.

Comment: put in  `debug.print i` line to print the value of `i` .... see if it changes

Comment: CName() and CAddress() should be globals for this to work, otherwise none of the elements will be maintained.  Also don't unload your form until you're done populating the text.

Comment: so the problem with i not counting was that I defined it publically in the module and it doesn't carry to the forms but when I tried defining CName() and CAddress() as public variables inside the form I get the compile error: "constants, fixed-length strings, arrays, user-defined types and declare statements not allowed as Public members of object modules." any idea how I can either reference this public variable from the form or sneakily define publically within the form? because it won't store the values unless publically defined.